# OpenGL / weight order independent transparency

Tags: python, algorithm, opengl-es, glsl

I'm trying to implement the algorithm described in http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/09/ that explains how to achieve order independent transparency. I've managed to implement a two-pass rendering but I'm unable to implement the single pass rendering as introduced in the listing 4 of the article (that is compatible with GL ES).

Here are three images that show the problem. First is the [reference](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/master/examples/transparency/reference.py) (that depends on display order), second, is the multi-pass [implementation](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/master/examples/transparency/oit-multipass.py) and last one is the [single-pass](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/master/examples/transparency/oit.py)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sources are in python using the [glumpy](http://glumpy.github.io) framework but I think they are quite self-explanatory.

Comment: Finally, I've manage to fix the problem. The links point to the solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the links?

Comment: I meant the multi-pass and single-pass implementation linked just above the pictures.